# Weird color codings in Firerox when using XSLT

Tags: firefox, xslt, colors

I am taking a Lynda course of XML.
When they try to demonstrate the XSLT, it doesn't work in IE or Firefox. 
When I try to see the source code in FF, I notice that the color of the opening and closing tags are different. The XSLT attribute is purple and its closing tag is red. I cannot upload the image I captured from the FF, but I am not allowed to upload images. It caught my eye that some opening and closing tags have different colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <-red

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/XSL/Transform"> <-red

<link<-purple rel= <-black "stylesheet"<-blue href=<-black "simpletransform.css"<-blue /><-black

<xsl:template<-purple match=<-black"/JavacoTea/"<-blue>
    <html><-**red**
    <head><-red
        <title<-purple>New Herbal Tea Available!</title>
    </head><-red
    <body><-red
        <img<-purple src=<-black"photos/javaco_tea_logo.gif"<-blue/><-black
        <h1>**<-purple**
        <xsl:value-of<-purple select=<-black"text()"<-blue /**<-red**><-black
        </h1>**<-red**
    </body><-red

    </html>**<-purple**
</xsl:template>**<-red**
 </xsl:stylesheet>**<-purple**
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing weird about that. It's just [code coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting), designed to make the code more readable. This site does it too:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simpletransform.css"/>

<xsl:template match="/JavacoTea/">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>New Herbal Tea Available!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="photos/javaco_tea_logo.gif"/>
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
        </h1>
    <unclosed tag
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> When they try to demonstrate the XSLT, it doesn't work in IE or
>   Firefox.

That's an entirely different matter.

---

FWIW, this is what your file looks like in **my** Firefox:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nope! The coloring I see here is different that the one I see on Firefox! As I mentioned h1 and HTML opening and closing tags have different colors... that's my point! I can't see any color in IE

Comment: @HedleyQuintana Different applications use different colorings. What seems to be the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `<xsl:template match="/JavacoTea/">` is a syntax error in the `match` attribute value, it should be `<xsl:template match="/JavacoTea">`.

And you need `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`, not the one you have in your sample.

Furthermore the top level `<link rel="stylesheet" href="simpletransform.css"/>` is not allowed, put that into the template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 


<xsl:template match="/JavacoTea">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>New Herbal Tea Available!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="simpletransform.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="photos/javaco_tea_logo.gif"/>
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
        </h1>

    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With all those corrections an XSLT processor should be able to execute your XSLT.